# Subquery last date/value from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to append the last fruit count from table2 to a query on table1.

```
table1                              table2                   
+--------+--------+-------+-----+   +--------+------+-------+
| fruit  | season | carbs | fat |   | fruit  | date | count |
+--------+------+---------+-----+   +--------+------+-------+
| apple  | summer |   21  |  0  |   | apple  | 2015 |  700  |
| banana | all yr |   27  |  0  |   | apple  | 2014 |  500  |
+--------+--------+-------+-----+   | banana | 2014 |  200  |
                                    | banana | 2013 |  300  |
                                    +--------+------+-------+

goal:
+--------+--------+-------+-----+------------+
| fruit  | season | carbs | fat | last_count |
+--------+------+---------+-----+------------+
| apple  | summer |   21  |  0  |     700    |
| banana | all yr |   27  |  0  |     200    |
+--------+--------+-------+-----+------------+
```

All I can come up with is something like this (not working):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.count AS last_count FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT fruit, count FROM table2 ORDER BY date DESC) t2 ON t1.fruit = t2.fruit
```

Also, I should be able to filter results based on values from table1 (e.g. `WHERE t1.carbs < 25`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to join `table1` to `table2` twice.  The first join is to the full `table2` which has the count, and the second join is to a subquery of `table2` which include only records for the latest fruit, for each fruit.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.count AS last_count
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.fruit = t2.fruit
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT fruit, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY fruit
) t3
    ON t2.fruit = t3.fruit AND
       t2.date  = t3.date
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. It does exactly what I need. However, the query takes quite long to execute so I may be going with 2 separate queries.

Comment: @gipadm Have you setup indices on the columns involved in the join (i.e. `fruit` and `date`)?  This should dramatically increase the speed of the query.

Comment: date and fruit were indexed on table2. I have now indexed fruit on table1. It runs a slightly faster.